# How can I hide the columns of a TreeTable in SAPui5

Tags: sapui5

I am currently working with TreeTable in sap.ui.table library. I just wanted to hide the table when there is no data in the table or hide few columns if no data. There is no method called setVisible() in TreeTable. Any suggestions?

my XML code

```
<table:TreeTable id="TreeTableApproval" rows="{path:'',parameters: {arrayNames:['item']}}" selectionMode="None"
                                          ariaLabelledBy="title">
                                    <table:columns>
                                        <table:Column width="13rem">
                                            <Label text="Approver ID"/>
                                            <table:template>
                                                <Text text="" wrapping="false"/>
                                            </table:template>
                                        </table:Column>
                                        <table:Column width="13rem">
                                            <Label text="Name"/>
                                            <table:template>
                                                <Text text="" wrapping="false"/>
                                            </table:template>
                                        </table:Column>
                                    </table:columns>
                                </table:TreeTable>
```

Model

```
{
    "contracts": {
        "item": [{
            "": "",
            "item": [{
                "": "",
                "": ""
            }, {
                "": "",
                "": ""
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setVisible()` method is borrowed from `sap.ui.core.Control`, It's not available in `sap.ui.table`. You can set the visibility eg., `this.byId("tableid").setVisible(false)` or `this.byId("columnid").setVisible(false)`.